# Pretty dynamic Url structure using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Iam having a url structure `http://mywebsite.com/trainer-profile.php?usr=DarwinDiaz&id=MTE4` Added the htaccess code and removed **.php** extension from the link.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^forums/ - [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Now my URL Structure is `http://mywebsite.com/trainer-profile?usr=DarwinDiaz&id=MTE4` . 
I want to convert this url to `http://mywebsite.com/trainer-profile/DarwinDiaz`.
Iam new to htaccess. Tried different htaccess codes but did't work
Thanks in advance

Comment: @anubhava once u have helped me in solving clean url using htacces.. But still now I dont know how to pass muliple variables in url. [link to my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18851994/how-to-create-clean-url-using-htaccess) Need little help in multiple parameters in url..

Comment: yes id=555, 555 is converted to its base64_encode()

Comment: @RakeshRajan: Please post a new question, better not to alter old questions.

Comment: Can u please edit the htaccess code and is it possible to change http://mywebsite.com/trainer-profile/DarwinDiaz/MTE4 @anubhava

Comment: Iam new to htaccess. Can u please edit my htaccess code to meet my requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^forums/ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(trainer-profile)\.php\?usr=([^\s&]+)&id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/%3? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^(trainer-profile)/(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ $1.php?use=$2&id=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Sorry.. its not changing my url structure. Copied the above code and updated htaccess.

Comment: In the browser enter URL as: `http://mywebsite.com/trainer-profile.php?usr=DarwinDiaz&id=MTE4` and see what it becomes.

Comment: Yes its working. Changed the url format but page css not working

Comment: css/js is different problem due to your use of relative paths. Use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
   You can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current URL.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest keeping it simple, like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /trainer-profile.php?usr=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

It puts out address like `http://mywebsite.com/DarwinDiaz/MTE4`, in which you have both `usr` and `id`, but without unnecessary elements.

Comment: Strange. Are you sure you're using the scheme I've posted?

Comment: Copied and updated the htaccess code with your code.