# clean url dynamic get parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hello i already create clean url 
  but i want this clean url get dynamic url

example

http://localhost:8081/olshop/products/filters/?weight=1&category=shrit

then using paging if more than 10 data

http://localhost:8081/olshop/products/filters/?weight=1&category=shrit/1

or user can filters only weight or only category or both

example

http://localhost:8081/olshop/products/filters/?category=shrit

using paging

http://localhost:8081/olshop/products/filters/?category=shrit/1

how to technique clean url like this in .htaccess file ?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule index$                                          index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^products/(\d+)$                                index.php?p=products&page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^products/filters/([^/]+)/?$                    index.php?p=products&weight=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^products/filters/(.*)\/(\d+)$                  index.php?p=products&weight=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$                                    index.php?p=$1  [QSA,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html             
</IfModule>
```

i already try link like this

http://localhost:8081/olshop/products/filters/?weight=1&category=shrit

this result 404 notfound

Help me thank's

Comment: Can you include what you have tried so far?

Comment: for your help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18851994/how-to-create-clean-url-using-htaccess

Comment: yes 
i already try link like this
http://localhost:8081/olshop/products/filters/?berat=1&kategori=kemeja 

result not found

Comment: @devpro this post this link  like movie.php?movie=name  in my link like this  index.php?p=products&weight=1&category=shirts  wil be result  http://localhost:8081/olshop/products/filters/?weight=1&category=shirt

Comment: why adding the pager /1 after parameters ?
Can't you use this kind of url instead: `http://localhost:8081/olshop/products/filters/1/?weight=1&category=shrit` ?

Comment: @FlorianLemaitre okay, no problem add paging after parameters, how to implementation in .htaccess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /olshop/
RewriteRule index$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^products/(\d+)$ index.php?p=products&page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^products/filters/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?p=products&page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^products/filters/?$ index.php?p=products&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1  [QSA,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
</IfModule>
```

Examples:

```
#This url:
http://localhost:8081/olshop/products/filters/1/?weight=1&category=shrit
#is rewrite to:
http://localhost:8081/olshop/index.php?p=products&page=1&weight=1&category=shrit

#This url:
http://localhost:8081/olshop/products/filters/?weight=1&category=shrit
#is rewrite to:
http://localhost:8081/olshop/index.php?p=products&weight=1&category=shrit
```

You can try your configuration with [this online tool](http://htaccess.mwl.be/)