# How to write cleaner url using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to get an improvised SEO via cleaner URL.
Below is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^ cleanurl2/podtadquery.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Below is what my url is currently looking like:

http://localhost/cleanerurl2/podtadquery.php?product=Actuators&subgroup=Electrical

What I am trying to achieve is

http://localhost/cleanerurl2/podtadquery.php/Actuators/Electrical

Please suggest how can I achieve this. Thanks in adance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18851994/how-to-create-clean-url-using-htaccess Googled it. Took 5 seconds.

Comment: @DiddleDot Its not like I didn't google it or worked enough from my end before I asked the question. Thanks for the post, but I am struggling to work my code out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code in /root/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
#1)
#Redirect from "/cleanerurl2/podtadquery.php?product=foo&subgroup=bar" to "/cleanerurl2/podtadquery.php/foo/bar"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /cleanerurl2/podtadquery\.php\?product=([^&]+)&subgroup=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /cleanerurl2/podtadquery.php/%1/%2? [NC,L,R]
#2)
#Now, internally redirect "/cleanerurl2/podtadquery.php/foo/bar" to "/cleanerurl2/podtadquery.php?product=foo&subgroup=bar
RewriteRule ^cleanerurl2/podtadquery\.php/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /cleanerurl2/podtadquery.php?product=$1&subgroup=$2 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **.htaccess** file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ index.php [L,NC]
```

Second line is to exclude jpg,jpeg,gif,bmp,png,tiff,css and js file. Other uri will be forwarded to index.php.

in **index.php**

```
<?php
$uri = rtrim( dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]), '/' );
$uri = trim( str_replace( $uri, '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ), '/' );

echo $uri;
?>
```

If you are using ubuntu server, please do below lines too

*Step 1.*

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

*Step 2.*
Open apache conf file

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Uncomment this line(about 187th line approx)

```
AccessFileName .htaccess
```

Then find the line where there is

```
<Directory /var/www/>
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride None
         Require all granted
</Directory>
```

replace "None" with "All"

```
<Directory /var/www/>
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
</Directory>
```

*Step 3.*
Restart apache

```
service apache2 restart
```