# Changing permalinks in different ways

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am wondering how to change all of these:

```
example.com/index.php <br />
example.com/index.php?item=1 <br />
example.com/article.php <br />
example.com/article.php?article=1
```

to the following:

```
example.com/home/ <br />
example.com/home/firstitem/ <br />
example.com/article/ <br />
example.com/article/firstarticle/
```

I know you can do this using `.htaccess`, but the problem is I don't know how.

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might helpful to you

[How to create clean url using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18851994/how-to-create-clean-url-using-htaccess)

and google it for clean url using htaccess.