# Rewrite blog URL - PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Can someone guide me how to rewrite http://www.website.co.uk/blog.php?story=85&title=contract-furniture-buying-guide to http://www.website.co.uk/blog/contract-furniture-buying-guide please using htaccess?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Google it for clean URLs using htaccess

Here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18851994/how-to-create-clean-url-using-htaccess?noredirect=1&lq=1)

This link may help

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Header unset ETag
FileETag None

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+movie\.php\?name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ movie/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^movie/([^/]+)/?$ movie.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```