# How can i change certain type URLs to another type using .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a website that every user has its own profile page.
I'm using php, so i use GET method to make URLs, for example:

```
example.com/users/dashboard?user=59
```

But I want this URL to be seen like:

```
example.com/users/dashboard/59
```

I've seen so many questions here and I decided to use the code below in my .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Header unset ETag
FileETag None

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+dashboard\.php\?user=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^dashboard/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^dashboard/([^/]+)/?$ dashboard.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and I know that it's wrong, But don't know how to fix it
so I appreciate any kind of help

Comment: This questions has been asked so here's a link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18851994/how-to-create-clean-url-using-htaccess

Comment: Thanks, so after seeing it, I edit my question

Comment: `RewriteRule ^ dashboard/%1? [R=301,L]` the space there is important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for all your answers
but i found another solution:
I changed my .htaccess code to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /4reza/users/index.php [L]
```

So I redirect every attempt to access to users folder to  index.php page and I use this code to manage any url with '4reza/users/ANY_NUMBER' format:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on')
    $link = "https";
else
    $link = "http";
$link .= "://";
$link .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$link .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$urlStr = str_replace("http://localhost/4reza/", "", $link);
$chunks = array_filter(explode('/', $urlStr));


if (count($chunks) == 2 and $chunks[0] == "users" and isset($chunks[1])) {
    if (is_numeric($chunks[1])) {
        ...
    }
}
```

4reza is my local folder for the website

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/users/dashboard/?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^user=([0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /users/dashboard/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^.*/users/dashboard/([\d]+)$ /users/dashboard?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: finaly, the url in browser is shown properly, but not the page content and it returns error 404... how do I fix this?

Comment: What is the real page URL? Sorry, I'm typing from the phone, can't get to my pc now. But it looks like the last RewriteRule doesn't work.

Comment: Can you enable debug information to tell us which exactly URL you get from the server?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how... Is there another way to find out the real URL that comes from the server?

Comment: If you have access to PHP code of your 404 page template, then just add there something like this: https://pastebin.com/RTbmmrki

Comment: i added a code like this, but it didn't worked: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /users/dashboard?user=$1 [L]

Comment: Reza, can you show the site? I need to understand if there is a page "/users/dashboard/index.php" on the site.

Comment: ok... but It's on the localhost on my laptop for testing. In my main folder, I've made a folder named testwebsite. In the recent folder, I've put the .htaccess file and the users folder and in the users folder, the dashboard file exists. Should I send a picture or something?

Comment: A weird thing happend... when I want to open my original url, /users/dashboard, I encounter 404 error!!!

Comment: Is there a file "/users/dashboard/index.php" from server root on your disk? The last RewriteRule means that if the request matches "/users/dashboard/_ANY_NUMBER_", it will be rewritten as "/users/dashboard/index.php?user=_ANY_NUMBER_". BUT if you don't have such a file "/users/dashboard/index.php", then you will get a 404 error page.

Comment: Did you add the last rules to the end of your .htaccess?